# How can the Python create nested objects?

Tags: python-3.x

How can the python create nested objects?

```
name = 'name'
print(name)
name

name.age = 'age'
print(name.age)
age

name.age.other = 'other'

print(name.age.other)
other
```

Is it even possible in python ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just need to wrap the value in your own class. You can't modify `str` itself.

```
class X(str):
    pass

name = X('name')
name.age = X('age')
name.age.other = 'other'
```